# Vuejs - How to display the attribute of an object in a loop with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

In my vuejs project I have an empty "CatalogItems" array. Thanks to a method I push data into this array, and when I do

```
console.log(this.catalogItems)
```

We see that my table contains 30 objects.

These objects contain several attributes (id, locale, ..), and among these attributes there is an object named "configuation" which contains the attribute "format".

[image]

On my front I have a loop with a v-for, its purpose is to display the different attributes of each object in my "CatalogItems" array.

```
<tr v-for="data in catalogItems" :key="data.value">
    <td>{{ data.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.locale }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.configuration }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.date }} <br> {{ data.heure }}</td>
    <td class="sousMenuTable flex justifyContentBetween">
      <span class="flex alignItemsCenter justifyContentCenter">{{ data.nombreDetecte }}</span>
      <span class="flex alignItemsCenter justifyContentCenter">{{ data.nombreInsere }}</span>
      <span class="flex alignItemsCenter justifyContentCenter">{{ data.nombreRejete }}</span>
    </td>
    <td>{{ data.type }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.load_frequency }}</td>
    <td class="marginRight15">
      <div class="ti-pencil flex justifyContentCenter alignItemsCenter"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="switchOnOff flex alignItemsCenter" :data-etat="data.etat" @click="switchStatus">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <span class="bold uppercase">{{ data.etat }}</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

My problem is that on my front end I can't display the "format" attribute of my "configuration" object present in my "CatalogItems" object array.

I tried to do this :

```
<td v-for="element in data.configuration">
  {{ element.format }}
</td>
```

But I have no visible results (nor any errors)

Comment: I don't see the `element.format` in the `console.log` result. That key exists in all the objects? Also, you could set up a reproducible example using vue playground - https://sfc.vuejs.org/. Now you know it for next times (:

Comment: Yes sorry ! I update it

Comment: So seems in some objects `format` is defined and in other ones it isn't, right?

Comment: I'm not sure... in the console.log I see a value for format or maybe I don't understand

Comment: You have to be sure. Check it. Also, as said, if you set up a reproducible example + vue playground, ppl will help you more easily. also, provide some input examples and your expected outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.configuration` looks like an object and not an array.

you should try to replace

```html
<td v-for="element in data.configuration">
  {{ element.format }}
</td>
```

by

```html
<td>
  {{ data.configuration.format }}
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have probably an error in the last interpolation `{{ element.format }}` - you are accessing field `format` of elements of `data.configuration`, you should remove `.format` (since it's undefined). You can see working example of what you are trying to achieve in this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-chatterjee-nzgwuv?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Thx for your answer :) 
I'll try but data.configuration have many attribute.. not only "format" so I have to focus the one I want

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why.. but! I show it to a friend, retry the same thing as I try the morning and it works..

The answer is

```
<td>{{ data.configuration.format }}</td>
```

Thanks for your answers! Have a nice day